# Issue with Session Id generation on JBoss AS 7.1.3

Tags: java, session, jboss, jboss7.x, sessionid

When we migrated from JBoss EAP 5.1.2 to version 6.0.1, the session id that is being created by my java code looks different.

With v5.1.2 session id looks like this : "1D5C800599BA12AD8A10FC54100E7F60"

With v6.0.1 session id looks like this: "u5tvf1Zd5A5F0-4 uwH6VdE7"

The earlier formatted SessionId is sent to another dependent application where it is parsed. Now interacting application sometimes able to parse and sometimes unable to parse the session id in new format.

I'm running app in standalone mode using standalone.xml, is there any way to create session id in which is in older format?

i tried adding -Dorg.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.SESSION_ID_ALPHABET=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789, but this didn't solved the issue.

How can i suppress +, -special characters?

By any chance clustering is leading to this, please suggest...

Comment: Both IDs are valid. What is the reason to *parse* a HTTP session ID? It's a string, and the content is implementation dependent. So there is no guarantee that you can convert it into a number for example. So "treat disease, not the symptom", and fix the receiver.

Comment: I got your point, i would like to know how to disable the clustering in JBoss EAP 6.0.1 when set up in standalone mode and by using standalone.xml.